# When the nested loop component is generated using the react props.children (i) map method, the number of components and the expected mismatch

Tags: javascript, reactjs

```js
let tourSections=[
{imgDetails:['images/detail2.jpg','images/detail3.jpg'],
location:'CA',date:'2017 2 12',},
{imgDetails:['images/detail1.jpg','images/detail3.jpg'],
location:'CA',date:'2017 2 12',},
]
function DetailCardsOnmobile(props){
let cardsitem=[];
for(let i=0;i<props.numTimes;i++)
cardsitem.push(props.children(i));
return <div>{cardsitem}</div>;
}


class DetailCardOnmobile extends React.Component {

render(){
const settings = {
dots: true,
infinite: true,
speed: 500,
slidesToShow: 1,
slidesToScroll: 1,
autoplay:true,
}
return(<DetailCardsOnmobile numTimes={tourSections.length}>{(index)=>
<Card key={index}>
<CardMedia className="cardMediah">
<Slider {...settings}>
{tourSections[index].imgDetails.map((key)=>
<div><img src={key} key={key} role="presentation"/></div> 
)}
</Slider>
</CardMedia>
</Card>
}
</DetailCardsOnmobile>
); 
}
}
```

run follow getting 4 images in per `<Slider />`. it is strange
no something wrong.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I can answer your question as asked, but a slight refactor to directly map over your tourSections and moving the child jsx to your stateless component should solve your issue and be more readable/maintainable.

```
let tourSections = [
  {
    imgDetails: ['images/detail2.jpg', 'images/detail3.jpg'],
    location: 'CA', date: '2017 2 12',
  },
  {
    imgDetails: ['images/detail1.jpg', 'images/detail3.jpg'],
    location: 'CA', date: '2017 2 12',
  },
]

function DetailCardsOnmobile(props) {
  return (
    <Card>
      <CardMedia className="cardMediah">
        <Slider {...props.settings}>
          {props.tourSection.imgDetails.map((img, index) =>
            <div><img src={index} key={img} role="presentation" /></div>
          )}
        </Slider>
      </CardMedia>
    </Card>
  );
}


class DetailCardOnmobile extends React.Component {

  render() {
    const settings = {
      dots: true,
      infinite: true,
      speed: 500,
      slidesToShow: 1,
      slidesToScroll: 1,
      autoplay: true,
    }
    return (
      <div>
        {tourSections.map((tourSection, index) => (
          <DetailCardsOnmobile key={index} settings={settings} tourSection={tourSection} />
        ))}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```